# Something is going wrong with this code and I can't find the bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need this code to work; docHeight appears as "undefined" but I it should be the "auxiliar" class height. The class height can change with the width of the window. Thank you

```js
var docHeight = $('.auxiliar').css("height");  
var variableXXX = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
 var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / docHeight;
     if ( scrollPercent >= 5 && variableXXX == false){
        variableXXX = true;
          alert($(document).scrollTop()); 
      }
});
```

Comment: What is docHeight before the scroll callback is executed?

Comment: taking the height of a class doesn't make sense. there can be any number of matches

Comment: it's not defined in the css div class

Comment: i've been trying tons of solutions @aw04 I've also tried giving docHeight 3 different values and making an if statement for them based on a class font size but it didn't work. could we open a chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as if you may be a little new but here is what's happening. The code that you think is getting the height is wrong.

```
var docHeight = $('.auxiliar').css("height");
```

This code sets the height value of the element to and empty string. Basically wiping it out. That's why you are getting undefined. It should  be.

```
var docHeight = $('.auxiliar').height();
```

This gets the height value of the element. 
 And place it inside of your scroll function or it will not recalculate with the scroll of the window. It will all way be the value it was on page load. I think you are wanting it to change.

Comment: I completely new but your solution fixed my problem! thanks